# Bootstrap unexpected result?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Basically my col's don't work or i am not doing something right? 
Here's an image i attached bellow
P.S.: I am a newbie with bootstrap just got started with it so please don't get mad at small mistakes.
I am using Bootstrap version 4
[Img here with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPRGv.png)

Here's my code

```
  <body>
 <header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/amf-logo.jpg" 
 alt="amfLogo" 
 width="130px" height="40px"></a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-
 target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
 aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Galerie</a>
  </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</nav>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"> <!-- you must close this -->

        <p> 


   acxzcxzcxzcxzvcxzvcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxz 

</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"

        <p> azcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxsdazcxxxxx </p>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div> 



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384-
 KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" ??? close it!

Comment: Run your HTML through a validator

Comment: Closed them but it still doesn't work. Text is still over each other

Comment: What do you have in your <head></head> tag

Comment: <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
 <style > * {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;


 }

Answer (score 0):

I put the code into codepen and the page displays properly there. See for yourself:

https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/mqagWO

```
I think this works fine.    :)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out...
If this doesn't work tell me what size screen you are viewing this on.

```
     <body>
 <header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/amf-logo.jpg" 
 alt="amfLogo" 
 width="130px" height="40px"></a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-
 target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
 aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Galerie</a>
  </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"> <!-- you must close this -->

        <p> 


   acxzcxzcxzcxzvcxzvcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxz 

</p>
```